# Set Expiry Local Storage

Tags: javascript, date, local-storage

I am trying to set a future expiry date with local storage but when I add a new

future time the date is always set at the current time only.  I am looking to set an attr to a div once the 1st page is loaded without using cookies.

Below is my function:

```
    if (localStorage.getItem("init") === null) {

    const item = {
        value: value,
        expiry: new Date().getTime() + ttl,
    }

    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))

}
}



// REMOVE KEY

function getWithExpiry(key) {
    const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
    // if the item doesn't exist, return null
    if (!itemStr) {
        return null
    }
    const item = JSON.parse(itemStr)
    const now = new Date()
    // compare the expiry time of the item with the current time
    if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
        // If the item is expired, delete the item from storage
        // and return null
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
        return null
    }
    return item.value
}




setWithExpiry('init', 'true', 300);

getWithExpiry('init'); 

if (localStorage.getItem("init") !== null) {

// add data-cp attr to inv code

ins.setAttribute('data-cp-first', 'true');


}
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you expect from this code. Seems the code is running just fine and doing so without errors (when accounting for the first function declaration line missing in your post). Your `ttl` is added to the `expiry` -time as expected, so if you could elaborate on what you want this code to do, it will be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by adjusting the TTL, my TTL wasn't set in milliseconds which was why it wasn't setting the expiry to a future date.
1 week to milliseconds = 604800000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Use same info:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/javascript/localstorage-with-ttl-expiry/

Here’s an overview of how we can achieve this:

```
Store the expected time of expiry along with the original information to be stored
When getting the item, compare the current time with the stored expiry time
If the current time is greater than to stored expiry time, return null and remove the item from storage, otherwise, return the original information.
```